# Android: 2 toasts same time

Tags: android, toast

Ok, I have 1 custom toast (xml layout) and it works great:

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout));
    ImageView image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.logo);        
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo);
    title = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.title);        
    txt = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
    toast = new Toast(appContext);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.setView(layout);
```

But when I try to make 2nd one same way I get error "Source not found" which doesn't really tell me anything about what's wrong.

```
    LayoutInflater infl = getLayoutInflater();
    View lay = infl.inflate(R.layout.toast_arrows, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_lay));                        
    toastarrows = new Toast(appContext);
    toastarrows.setGravity(Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    toastarrows.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toastarrows.setView(lay);                
    toastarrows.show();
```

I'd like those 2 toasts to appear almost same time in different places of the screen.
Anyone can tell me please what's wrong with this code?

Comment: Debug shows that toastarrows value is null. I don't rly get what's different in these 2 examples.

Comment: It's like the line "toastarrows = new Toast(appContext);" is the one that cause problems. Any idea why? :/ Toastarrows is declared as "private Toast toastarrows" earlier and appContext is just getApplicationContext variable.

Comment: ok, new Toast(getApplicationContext()) for some reason works but I still can't see the 2nd toast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are sure that you can show 2 Toast at the same time? 
i'm not sure about this, i tried it but i can display only one Toast.
you have tried to show only the second one?

Comment: I gave up and reformatted the 1st one to show both. Now fighting with complicated XML layout ;) 2nd one alone works, but shows only after the 1st one ends.

Comment: so we can add only one Toast at the time :) maybe Toast class use some static method and variable so we can't modify it at the same time. :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if you do really create two toasts at the sametime they will still be shown one after another in the same place. So I think your stuggling's vain.